# Using StaggeredGridView with HashMap in Android

Tags: java, android, json

Im refering and using Etsy StaggeredGridView to load data from json by AsyncTask into GridView from path: http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/

**1. In StaggeredGridActivity class I try to change data type:**

from:

```
private ArrayList<String> mData;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData;
```

**2. And in SampleAdapter class, I try to change:**

from:

```
    public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    ...
       public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                     ArrayList<String> objects) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
       ...
       }
    ...
    }
```

to

```
    public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> {
    ...
       public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> objects) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
       ...
       }
    ...
    }
```

And then, it seem there is an exception in StaggeredAdapter class at line:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getItem(position), vh.imgView);
```

with an alert:

```
Cannot resolve method 'displayImage(java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView)'
```

How to fix and change data type of ArrayList to HashMap

Thank you !!

Comment: Can not resolve symbol... ? which symbol ? is it really declared !

Comment: I have updated alert, you can review it

Comment: It cannot resolve, because the `displayImage` method expects a String as a first argument, but your passing a `HashMap` instead. The first argument should be a `URI`. But what is in your `HashMap` ?

Comment: As you said, the first argument should be a URI, but in my AsyncTask class, I want to get Key-Value of json URL, that is reason I used HashMap,  for example: HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();map.put(TAG_ID, song_id);map.put(TAG_NAME, name);